# Is there something like session id or cookie in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, sessionid

How can I distinguish different users with actionscript, or is that possible?

Comment: How do you mean "distinguish" different users?  Like Martin mentioned, LSOs are the Flash version of cookies.  However, these are easily forged / manipulated, so as long as it is not something you doing where security could be a concern, LSOs are the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Local Shared Objects

References:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/articles/lso/

The actionscript reference for LSOs is at:

http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary648.html